# How to test a function in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

```js
const updateSession = async (emitter, dbModel, center_id, session_id, data) => {

    if (await dbModel.update('session', {center_id, session_id, data})) {
        const result = {
            center_id: `k${center_id}`,
            session_id: session_id,
            ...data
        } ;
        emitter.emit('updateSession', {
            operationType: 'update',
            operationOn: 'session',
            data: result
        }) ;
    } else throw new Error('500 Internal Server Error') ;
}
```

> `emitter` is an EventEmitter
>
> `dbModel` is a module to interact with database
>
> `center_id` is a number
>
> `session_id` is a string
>
> **All of the above are same in all cases**

I need to test this fucntion in jest with 3 different cases where

> case 1 : `data = {available_capacity1: 4, available_capacity2: 6}`
>
> case 2 : `data = {available_capacity1: 4}`
>
> case 3 : `data = {available_capacity2: 6}`

Conditions :

> In case 1 the test should pass if `data` passed to callback of event
> listener, that is :`emitter.on('updateSession', callback)`, has both
> `available_capacity1` and `available_capacity2` properties in `data.result`
> object
>
> In case 2 the test should pass if `data` passed to callback of event
> listener has only `available_capacity1` property in `data.result` object
>
> In case 3 the test should pass if `data` passed to callback of event
> listener has only `available_capacity2` property in `data.result` object

I would like to know how can I write a test for the above mentioned cases in jest

any help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to do is not unit testing, and is therefore discouraged. You want to test the callback passed to `emitter.on()` but you're doing that in another file.

Comment: not the callback, data passed into the callback. which is the result of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test a callback function in jest you should use the alternate form of its test function where you consume a callback argument you invoke when you determine the test has ended. More info here: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks

Here is an example on how to implement your specific test cases, these are of course not perfect but should get you an idea of how to do them yourself.

```
test('callback data has available_capacity1 and available_capacity2', done => {
  const data = { available_capacity1: 4, available_capacity2: 6 };
  const emitter = new EventEmitter();
  emitter.once('updateSession', arg => {
    try {
      expect(arg.data).toHaveProperty('available_capacity1');
      expect(arg.data).toHaveProperty('available_capacity2');
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });
  updateSession(emitter, dbModel, center_id, session_id, data);
});

test('callback data has only available_capacity1', done => {
  const data = { available_capacity1: 4 };
  const emitter = new EventEmitter();
  emitter.once('updateSession', arg => {
    try {
      expect(Object.keys(arg.data).length).toBe(1);
      expect(arg.data).toHaveProperty('available_capacity1');
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });
  updateSession(emitter, dbModel, center_id, session_id, data);
});

test('callback data has only available_capacity2', done => {
  const data = { available_capacity2: 6 };
  const emitter = new EventEmitter();
  emitter.once('updateSession', arg => {
    try {
      expect(Object.keys(arg.data).length).toBe(1);
      expect(arg.data).toHaveProperty('available_capacity2');
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });
  updateSession(emitter, dbModel, center_id, session_id, data);
});
```

Comment: I should use a assertion to see if there's minimum one expect statement ryt ? or not emitting the event will make the function pass ?